# New to c++ print divisors function

Tags: c++

Very new to c++ and just trying to do a basic function where I print the divisors of a number but not the number itself. IE print divisors of 6 would return 1,2,3. I keep getting the error:

> no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are
>   ‘std::basic_ostream’ and ‘void’)

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

int x;

void printdivisors(int x){

    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=x;++i)
    {
        if(x%i==0)
            cout<<" "<<i;
    }  


};


int main(){ 
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout << "\nDivisors of " << n <<" are" << printdivisors(n);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't do `std::cout << printdivisors(x)`. Just call the function afterwards

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong?

The return type of `printdivisors` is `void`. Hence, the term `printdivisors(n)` evaluates to a `void`. You cannot insert a `void` to `cout`. Hence,

```
cout << "\nDivisors of " << n <<" are" << printdivisors(n);
```

is a problem. Change it to:

```
cout << "\nDivisors of " << n <<" are";
printdivisors(n);
```